# Dont Listen Until Message Is Processed Windows Service

Tags: c#

I am creating a windows service that is listening for messages in an MQ. My current code seems to be reprocessing the same message over and over again. I want to alter this code to only start listening to for messages After the current message is done processing

Here is my current code that keeps looping the same message(Processing of a message takes about 6 min)

```
 protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            var maincode = new Thread(ProcessCode);
            maincode.Name = "dud";
            maincode.IsBackground = false;
            maincode.Start();

        }

    void ProcessCode()
        {
            do
            {
                theListener.MessageReceived += new EventHandler<MessageReceivedEventArgs>(MQ_MessageReceived);

                IBM.WMQ.MQMessage mqMessage = theListener.Listen("manager", "theQueue");

                Thread.Sleep(5000);
            } while (true);
        }
```

Comment: If you are reprocessing the same message it may be necessary to acknowledge the message after processing to actually remove it from the queue.  All this depends on how MQ works (I do not know MQ) and, I guess, the version.  From a quick search it appears as though you can consume messages in different ways so you'll have to check that you are following the correct procedures as per the configuration you are using from the client side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are already receiving the message by using the Listen method. I'm not sure why you are hooking into the `MessageReceived` event. I would probably rename the `MQ_MessageReceived` event to just `HandleMessage` remove the MessageReceived Event Handler and just do something simple like.

`void ProcessCode() 
    {
        while(true) {
            //assuming that the Listen method blocks and waits for a message to be received.
            var message = theListener.Listen("manager, "theQueue");
            HandleMessage(message);
        }
    }`

also note that you probably want to put in some logic to be able to stop processing messages for when you need to shut the service down.